# What happened to woodman.com?

Tags: disassembly

I had bookmarked woodman.com/crackz a couple years back because it looked like it had some good content for learning how to reverse engineer, but I never had the time/vested interest to dig in deep and really start learning. I finally have the time and interest now but I just tried to go to the site and it seems like it's gone. Does anyone know of a mirror/archive of the site or what happened to it? Also if there isn't a mirror/archive what is another good site similar to its content?

Comment: Are you looking for something like this: [Is there something like DVWA (Damn Vulnerable Web Application) for reverse engineering?](http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/14170/is-there-something-like-dvwa-damn-vulnerable-web-application-for-reverse-engin)

Comment: some kind of lame trouble with isps getting complaints about tools being classified as awesome    lack of interest  and or new content  forums not being vogue enough for the mobile kids  etc etc has constrained woodmann.com form being up  may be some day it might be back atleast there is a wish to keep it up who knows what future holds

Comment: Well it is up again @ 185.62.190.110/forum

Answer (score 3):

It seems that woodmann.com, the RCE community, is no longer available and displays an ad.
 Due to it's robots.txt blocking archive.org requests,There are no wayback machine archives.
However if you want to find other communities I suggest
https://www.reddit.com/r/ReverseEngineering/ 
https://tuts4you.com/
You can get a free book called RE4B (reverse engineering for beginners) online
and there is another community called openrce
(couldn't post >3 links because I have no reputation.)

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for that necromancy, but it seems that it's actually possible to reach latest state of the website before it was taken down:
https://web.archive.org/web/20220330081653/http://www.woodmann.com/forum/index.php
You can download zipped (rared) archives of the forum as well as other mirrors that were kept alive thanks to Woodmann (like Fravia!).

Answer (score 1):

Crackz is archived: https://web.archive.org/web/20110523025938/http://www.woodmann.com/crackz/index.html

I'd also recommend [www.crackmes.de](http://www.crackmes.de) .. they shut up shop some time ago but there are/were plenty of mirrors (http://crackmes.cf/archive/).

Answer (score 0):

If you still need the pages, download the full archive using the following link(The file size is around 452 MB):
[CracksZ's Pages](https://forum.tuts4you.com/files/file/2336-crackzs-reverse-engineering-page-1997-2012/)